# Hibernate many to one attribute is null when persisting by id

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following one to many relationship:

```
@Entity
class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_user", nullable = false)
    private Integer idUser
    // Other attribute
}

@Entity
class Car {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_car", nullable = false)
    private Integer idCar

    @Column(name = "id_user", nullable = false)
    private Integer idUser

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_user", referencedColumnName = "id_user", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User user
    // Other attributes
}
```

When creating a `car` and setting `idUser` as follows:

```
Car car = new Car();
car.setIdUser(idUser);
entityManager.persist(car);
```

**I would expect `car.getUser()` to lazy load the user with the provided id, but it is `null`.** How can I initialize the lazy behavior on this new entity? I don't want to do `car.setUser(someUser)`, because that would mean I have to retrieve the user myself.

Comment: Are you sure that `User` should be of type `Integer`. Your mapping looks quite artistic and most likely will not work, could you post the full `Car` and `User` class?

Comment: Yes, my bad, it should be of type `User` ofcourse

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new user and set the id of the user and add it to the car

```
User user = new User();
user.setId(userId);//userId is the id of user in db
car.setUser(user)
```

Comment: This still does not allow me to do e.g. `car.getUser().getName()`. I would expect to get the full blown `User` entity.

Comment: The attributes of `User` remain null, even when I call `flush()`.

Answer (score 0):

When hibernate fails to initialize the proxy, a `LazyInitializationException` is thrown. As you are getting `null` instead, the user is most likely not persisted at all.

The setter you are using `car.setIdUser(idUser);` looks like to be setting the id and not the entity, which is most likely not what you want to do.

You should do sth. like `car.setUser(userEntity)` and remove the mapping for the foreign key entirely:

```
@Column(name = "id_user", nullable = false)
private Integer idUser;
```

If you are not persisting the `User` entity before persisting the `Car` you should have a look at `CascadeType.PERSIST` **Note** adding `CascadeType.ALL` would remove the `User` if the car is deleted.

https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/

Comment: The thing is that I have hardcoded ids (here: `idUser`) in my application (sounds bad, but in my case it's necessary) corresponding to entities that are certainly available in the database. The idea was that I could assign such an id to a new entity (here: `car`), without needing to retrieve the `User` that I'm referencing to. I hoped that Hibernate would enable me to retrieve the `User` by only assigning the id. I suspected that there was a was to initialize the proxy stuff that Hibernate uses to lazy load, but it seems this is not possible.

Comment: Since there is no better solution at hand, I ended up querying the `User` and then indeed doing `car.setUser(user)`.